# Finding a point on a circle given radius and Y intercept

Tags: trigonometry, circles

Sorry this one is probably very obvious but its been a long time since trigonometry class.

I have a circle with a known radius, lets say $R = 2$, how to I find $x$ when $y = 1.5$?

$y$ will never be greater than $R$ so I don't need to worry about that.

Do I need to normalize to a unit circle?
What trig to I need?

Thanks in advance for helping this lost programmer.

Comment: have you the coordinates of the middle Point of the circle?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are infinitely many circles with $y=1.5$ with that description. We're missing a vital piece of information. Is the circle centred on the origin for example? Or is there a different piece of information?

Comment: Yes circle centered on 0,0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then you have the equation of the circle $$x^2+y^2=4$$ plugging $$y=1.5$$ in your equation then you will get
$$x^2+1.5^2=4$$ can you solve this?

Comment: Yes I can. Thanks.
Feel quite silly now but I need to use this stuff so infrequently.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: ok you are welcome, nice that i could help you!